# Make UI Tabs rotate

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm wondering how to make jquery tabs rotate. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {initialIndex:' . rand(0,$i-1) . ', effect:"fade", fadeInSpeed:1000, fadeOutSpeed:0, rotate:3000});
});
```

Comment: What do you mean rotate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetTimeout to call a rotator function each X second and what the functions does is it triggers a click event on the tabs with the order you want. click 1'st tab, wait x seconds, click 2'nd tab, etc... You should assign each tab a different ID or class or something that you can distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for rotate

```
$j("ul.tabs").tabs( /* options */).tabs("rotate", 3000);
```